# Mathematical Limerick

Tags: arithmetic

*A dozen, a gross and a score,*

*Plus three times the square root of four,*

*Divided by seven,*

*Plus five times eleven,*

*Is nine squared and not a bit more.*

Question $1$: Does this limerick actually work?

Question $2$: Can you find a better one?

Hint: $$((12+144+20)+(3 \cdot √4))/7 + (5 \cdot 11) = 9^2+0$$.

Comment: While clever, this really had very little to do with mathematics.

Comment: See https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10001.3-8.shtml

Comment: I am sorry to whoever edited first, but you cannot remove the zero on the RHS. It is the author's intention to put the zero to represent *and not a bit more*

Comment: Oh well... Posts being closed... The circle of (math.stackexchange) life...

Comment: By the way, I am quite new to math.stackexchange and I have probably broke about twenty unspoken rules.

Comment: Including the rule "Don't speak about speaking about the unspoken rules".

Comment: alternative rendition of Leigh Mercer’s mathematical limerick:
Twelve, one-forty-four, and twenty,
plus three times root 4 is plenty,
but divide it by seven,
add five times eleven,
and it's nine squared plus a number that's empty.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wGt1gz-e5-w

Comment: the integral of t squared dt
from 1 to 3 times the square root of 3
is equal to the cosine of 3 pi over 9
plus the log of the sixth root of e
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ArAoskd69bM
alternative rendition:
The integral z-squared dz
From one to the cube root of three
Times the cosine
Of three pi over nine
Equals log of the cube root of e.
https://www.futilitycloset.com/2007/06/27/a-mathematical-limerick/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879179/is-there-any-similar-math-limerick

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079635/epsilon-delta-quasi-limerick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try a very simple one,

*fifty and a sixty
is not a seventy
 nor a ninety
 but a twenty 
 below a hundred and thirty.*

Comment: Good job, Win Vineeth!